# Image tracking not working with Google Analytics

Tags: email, google-analytics

I'm trying to add Google Analytics to my newsletters - sending via email.

I found img tag logging ( `<img src="https://www.google-analytics.com/collect?v=1&utmac=UA-123456789-1&ec=email&ea=open&t=event" />` - https://blog.mailtrap.io/google-analytics-for-emails/ ), but it's not working because of src link is replaced by mail engines (gmail, ymail,..).

Also, I tried to track it by opening on my own web-site: I added img tag on my web-site's main page and loaded many times, but Google Analytics did not report it (logging is working on my Google Analytics account: I've tried to add Google Analytics scripts in head and it was logged - function gtag and its scripts..).

How to use Google Analytics in mails?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lot of browser-based mailboxes will cache the image on their server instead. I don't think there is a way around that.

Regarding why nothing is tracking, in the link you provided as well as [documentation from Google](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/email) requires other parameters as well. You're missing at least the client id `cid` parameter, adding it should work.

You can verify with [the hit builder](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/hit-builder/).

Comment: You are right! Data was logged when I added 'cid' parameter. Thanks